# Why NULL needs typecasting with blocks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, objective-c-blocks

See this scenario :

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) UIImage * (^bgImageBlock)(void);
```

Defination of `bgImageBlock` block variable :

```
objDrawing.bgImageBlock = ^(){
         return (UIImage *)NULL;
    };
```

bgImageBlock has return type UIImage that if I pass NULL like this :

```
objDrawing.bgImageBlock = ^(){
         return NULL;
    };
```

Would give compile time error : `Incompitable block pointer type assigning to UIImage.`

Whereas if I take simple UIImage variable and assign it NULL, It is absolutely fine. Then why in case of Blocks It can't accept NULL without typecast. ?

Comment: You should file a bug report with Apple. An error message using the word "Incompitable" is unacceptable.

Comment: @gnasher729 yea i am thinking of doing so... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler infers the block return type from the kind of object you return, if you don't explicitly tell it. So, in this case:

```
objDrawing.bgImageBlock = ^(){
     return NULL;
};
```

...I assume it's seeing the `NULL` and inferring that the return type of your block is `void *`, the type of `NULL`. This doesn't match your property type, so the compiler complains. (Note that the error is about the "block pointer type"; it's a mis-match between the declaration of your block property and the block you're trying to store in it.)

If you explicitly tell it your type, you should be able to use your simple NULL return:

```
objDrawing.bgImageBlock = ^UIImage*(){
     return NULL;
};
```

That the block type is inferred from the return type is documented [in the Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html):

> The return type is optional and is inferred from the return statements. If the return statements return a value, they all must return a value of the same type. If there is no value returned the inferred type of the Block is void; otherwise it is the type of the return statement value.

This inference of the return type, and the fact that the compiler checks the pointer types for you, and produces the error you're getting if there's a mis-match, is mentioned in the [2013 WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/) "Advances in Objective-C". (See the part titled "return type inference").

Comment: So with no return type declared, it defaults to void. That means simply `return;` should be fine, right? Otherwise, if you declare the return to be `id` you can get away with `return nil;` which would be more traditional Objective-C but still allow returning an object right?

Answer (score 0):

Your block is expecting the type `UIImage*`. However, `NULL` being a pointer, it just does not recognize it to be pointing to anywhere of the type `UIImage*` (be it nothing). Bam, error.

However, you are now casting a pointer. It does not actually do anything at runtime. *It just modifies the type being pointed-to*, which then affects subsequent operations on the resulting value. But the actual pointer value will remain the same through the cast.

While the actual pointer remains same (all though, the value being pointed to is nothing), it is now pointing to a **type** that the block is expected to be returning. All is well. :)

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is of type `void *`, so the block is inferred to have return type `void *`, and non-Objective-C-object pointer types (like `void *`) are not compatible with Objective-C-object pointer types (like `UIImage *`). Instead, you should use `nil`, which is also a null pointer, but of type `id`, which is compatible with all Objective-C-object pointer types.